# nodename nor servname provided, or not known on tcp connection in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am tring to understand the socket connections in python and everytime i am tring to connect to a url it's giving me this error:

```
nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

which i have no idea why? And sometimes it's only showing `301` and never a `200` status!

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "Whatever url i am giving"
server_address = (host, 80)
request_header = request_header = 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: '+host+'\r\n\r\n'

try:
    s.connect(server_address)
    s.send(request_header.encode('utf-8'))
    result = s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
    while (len(result) > 0):
       print(result)
       result = s.recv(4096)
except Exception as ex:
    print("Unexpected error:", ex)   


s.close()
```

I know there are other questions but that doesn't satisfy my query. Can someone point me out what's happening here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't connect to a *URL*. You connect to a host. When I assign `host = stackoverflow.com`, for example, your code works fine.

The socket layer itself knows nothing about URLs. A URL includes the path you supply to the host's HTTP server after you've connected. So, if you wish to retrieve, say, the URL "http://stackoverflow.com/questions", you connect to the host "stackoverflow.com", then provide this as the first line in the HTTP request:

```
GET /questions HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

This request (to stackoverflow.com) will in fact deliver a 301 response. 301 is a redirect response, telling you that the document you seek is available from a different host or service. This is an increasingly common response as most "http" sites now redirect the client to their corresponding "https" service.

If the host name you provide is not a valid hostname (for example, if you attempt to connect to "szackoverflow.com"), the hostname lookup that's being done automatically on your behalf will fail, resulting in a `socket.gaierror` exception ("gai" => `getaddrinfo`). On my linux system, that looks like this:

```
Unexpected error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

On a different operating system, the text provided with that error might be worded differently.

Comment: yeah i actually figured that out already. Thanks for the answer.